# JMX connection to JBoss EAP 7.4 + LDAP is not connected

Tags: java, ldap, jmx, jboss-eap-7

I am facing JMX connection issue on JBoss EAP

**My runtime environment** : (Linux OS) - SSL enabled JBoss EAP 7.4.10.GA running on Open JDK 11.0.19 (OpenLogic) & management console is secured with LDAPS server.

**JMX Client**: is working fine when using OpenJDK 12 which is running on the same Linux Machine. When upgrading the Java from 12 to 17 (OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+70 , JMX connection is failure and getting the below exception.

***Note** : Jboss-cli-client.jar is added on the class path*

How to resolve it ?

```
Oct 27, 2023 10:01:31 AM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
Oct 27, 2023 10:01:31 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Oct 27, 2023 10:01:31 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.Final
Oct 27, 2023 10:01:31 AM org.jboss.remotingjmx.Util warnDeprecated
WARN: The protocol 'https-remoting-jmx' is deprecated, instead you should use 'remote+https'.
Oct 27, 2023 10:01:31 AM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection handleException
ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener.allMechanismsFailed(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:114)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:453)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:243)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:199)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:113)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$DelegatingChannelListener.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:1092)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:272)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:253)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:335)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalRemotingConnect(RemotingConnector.java:239)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.internalConnect(RemotingConnector.java:158)
    at org.jboss.remotingjmx.RemotingConnector.connect(RemotingConnector.java:105)
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown Source)
    at JavaInstrumentation$1.run(JavaInstrumentation.java:845)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UPDATE**

1. **JBoss EAP Admin console is able to login without any issues when  running both JDK 12 & 17. Only facing JMX client connectivity issue  with 17**
2. **JVM OPTIONS used on the server**

   JAVA_OPTS:  -server
   -Xlog:gc*:file="/opt/app/logs/eap/gc.log":time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M
   -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/app/jboss/Dumps/HeapDumps/  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldaps=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED
3. **JVM OPTIONS used on the JMX Client**

   [-Xrs, -XX:+SuppressFatalErrorMessage, -Xss2m,
   -Djavax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl,
   -XX:ErrorFile=/dev/null, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/null, -XX:-CreateCoredumpOnCrash, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED, -Xmx512m, -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=900, -Dhttp.keepAlive=false, -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=, -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false]

Is anything need to add additionally on the client side. ?

Answer (score 0):

Client and servers negotiate the cipher to use when they establish a TLS connection. Moving from Java 12 to 17 changed that list.

You can see what your client supports with [Ciphers.java provided by Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html). Run the script with both JVMs.

Compare that list with the [list of ciphers supported by the server with Openssl](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html).

If you can, upgrading the server to modern ciphers is the way to go.

Comment: There is no SSL / TLS errors or exceptions when running jmx client program (which is JAVA 17 )

Comment: You lost me there. Your question says the JMX Client works with a version 12 JVM, but not with a version 17 JVM. Your comment now says it works with a version 17 JVM. Which one is it?

Comment: JBoss EAP Admin console is able to login with JDK 12 & 17.   But JMX client is not connecting when using 17 only (JMX client working fine with 12)